# updating Label from non IBAction methods

Tags: cocoa, label, ibaction

I have a method

```
-(NSArray *) updateLabel:(id)sender {

 [somelabel setStringValue:@"test"];

}
```

But the label never gets updated. If I move this out to an IBAction method, the label gets updated. Is there a way to update the label from within a non IBAction method ? Thanks.

Comment: Are the semicolon errors in the code intentional?

Comment: sorry about the typos :)

Comment: how and when do you  want to update your label?

Comment: I call updateLabel from an IBAction method and in here I want to update the label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out. Was blocking my main thread so the UI was not getting updated. Using GCD to update UI on main thread and run tasks on another queue solves this issue.

Answer (score 0):

- Are you actually *calling* the method anywhere?
- Why is `NSArray*` the return type?
- What platform is this on?
- "If I move this out to an IBAction method"  Does this mean linking it to a button?

If you want to move this out of an IBAction method, you simply call it: `[self updateLabel:nil];`

Comment: Yes, I call this updateLabel method from an IBAction method. It's on 10.7.3. The IbAction method is called on clicking a button. This calls the NSArray method and in here I want to update label's as I get done with tasks.